# mysql update from complex select nested query

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
  select
      p.*
   from
      ( select
          
              pc.product_id
           from
             oc_product_to_category pc
           where
      
              pc.category_id in ( 6,17,18,21,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,286,293,328,329, 301 )
           group by
              pc.product_id
           having
  
                  sum( case when pc.category_id = 301 
                            then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
              AND 
     
                  sum( case when pc.category_id in ( 6,17,18,21,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,286,293,328,329 )
                        then 1 else 0 end ) > 0  ) JustQualified
             JOIN oc_product p
            on JustQualified.product_id = p.product_id
```

and I want to update table oc_product as:

```
  SET oc_product.mycolumn = 22
```

for the above query.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I read the text in the above url, however it is a generic post about the construction of SQL queries, It didn't help me regarding my question.

Comment: Yep, we get one like this now and then

Answer (score 0):

You can use the complex query to produce Ids and to use them like this:

```
UPDATE  oc_product
SET     mycolumn = 22
FROM    oc_product
WHERE   oc_product.product_id IN
        (
            <complex_query...>    --> Query should return product ids
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 update oc_product set oc_product.mycolumn  = 22 where 
  oc_product.product_id = (
select
     distinct p.product_id 
   from
      (


select * from (
 select
          
              pc.product_id
           from
             oc_product_to_category pc
           where
      
              pc.category_id in ( 6,17,18,21,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,286,293,328,329, 301 )
           group by
              pc.product_id
           having
  
                  sum( case when pc.category_id = 301 
                            then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
              AND 
     
                  sum( case when pc.category_id in ( 6,17,18,21,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,286,293,328,329 )
                        then 1 else 0 end ) > 0  ) JustQualified
             JOIN oc_product p
            on JustQualified.product_id = p.product_id) tmp1
)
```

Comment: it produces error: You can't specify target table 'oc_product' for update in FROM clause

Comment: try query 2 since mysql maybe doesn't support the first syntax

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias. Please test code before posting. It just clutters up the internet otherwise.

Comment: @Strawberry I hope you will create all those tables , run it and test it for OP and don't worry too much about internet.

Comment: I don't need to (and, besides, I certainly would have no intention of doing so). Syntax errors occur whether tables are created or not.